# How does the Android life cycle demo make a dialogue box?

Tags: android, lifecycle

I am looking at the life cycle demo provided on the android dev website (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).  It makes a dialogue box appear when the pause button is clicked, but I cannot figure out where in the code it makes the dialogue activity into a dialogue box instead of a normal activity.  I am trying to implement this in my own app so that I can experiment with pausing, but I just do not understand where the dialogue box comes from.  Where is the code for making the activity appear as a dialogue box?

Here is the code for the UI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@color/dark_yellow"
    android:padding="12dip"
    >

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dialog_text"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium"
    android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"
    android:paddingBottom="12dip"
    />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_finish_dialog"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/btn_finish_dialog_label"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:onClick="finishDialog"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for the class associated with the UI

/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

```
package com.example.android.lifecycle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;

public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
    }

    /**
     * Callback method defined by the View
     * @param v
     */
    public void finishDialog(View v) {
        DialogActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see what you're referring to can you post a link to the code your talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog appears when the button is clicked. The handler method is:

```
public void startDialog(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, DialogActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This handler is defined in the `Activity*.java` files.

This handler is mapped to the button via the `onClick` property in the `activity_*.xml` files:

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_start_dialog"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_start_dialog_label"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_finish_a"
        android:onClick="startDialog"
        />
```

This property specifies what function on the activity should be called in the event the user clicks the button.

When the `DialogActivity` is started, it loads its layout from the `activity_dialog.xml` file.

As @RSenApps points out, to make the activity look like a dialog you need to specify the theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <activity android:name=".DialogActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand what you have said, but what I don't understand is where it says that the layout of the activity called when the button is clicked should be a dialogue box and not any other layout.

Comment: Yes, I think I was editing at the same time you were commenting :-)

Comment: OH! It's in the manifest!  Thank you!  I spent at least an hour trying to figure this out.  I'll see if that solves my problem later.

Comment: Second question, why does the activity pause when the dialogue come up?

Comment: Short answer is it pauses because it is no longer the top level activity but is still partially visible. Longer short answer is when an activity is no longer active (on top) it should release resources that it no longer needs (like GPS or something) so the new top level activity can use them. These resources are then reacquired when the activity is resumed. If completely hidden by the new activity then the old activity will be stopped and potentially removed from memory. Since it is still partially visible it cannot be stopped and removed since that would look pretty odd to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about this specific example, but in general, to make an activity look like a dialog, place the theme in your manifest (under your activity):

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```